# Overriding style without !important in plain CSS

Tags: css, google-amp

I am designing a Google-AMP based webpage. There are some limitations of Google-AMP that css `!important` property can't be used.

In Google-AMP, a built-in style is using `!important` property as follows:

```
amp-sidebar {
  max-width: 80vw!important;
}
```

In my scenario I need to update a style `max-width` to `100vw`. How can I update the `amp-sidebar` to `100vw` without using `!important`?

PS: JavaScript or Inline-CSS can't be used. I need to make changes using only CSS.

Here is the fiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/mutafaf/cdb3dnqz/

Comment: can u override the built-in style which uses !important by using a parent container and referencing.

eg.

.parent-container amp-sidebar {
  max-width: 100vw !important;
}

Comment: @FranklinPious I have tried using parent container but not working.
Also assigned another class later but even that doesn't worked.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a fiddle.?

Comment: You can't. AMP doesn't allow !important tags as they don't want to run the risk of something being broken. They use them and once something has !important you can't override it with your own styling.This is intentional on their part so you can't modify AMP components.

Comment: @FranklinPious here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mutafaf/cdb3dnqz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `padding` on both sides `left` and `right`. So the div took full screen.

```
amp-sidebar {
  padding-left: 10vw;
  padding-right: 10vw;

}
```

So width allowed was 80vw + padding(left & right) 20vw = 100vw.
That solved my problem.

Hope this helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The most precise selector will take the lead.

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    Hi
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#bar {
  background-color: green;
}
#foo #bar {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here, you will have a blue background!

So maybe you can build a rule with `#parent amp-sidebar`

Comment: Actually it does! Look at the inspector, you'll see in your jsfiddle that i takes the right property. You also need to add !important to the min-width to override the plugin property. https://jsfiddle.net/u3cy5mny/2/